button disable issue on the next
I am using Next.js with Yup for validation. When I click the submit button, it should disable immediately if validation errors exist. However, the button is not disabled immediately. Instead, it disables only after I tap elsewhere on the screen. This issue occurs on mobile devices but not on laptops or PCs.
chcode :
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting,isValid },
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    resolver: yupResolver(ValuationSchema),
  });

button code:
            <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="contained"
            fullWidth
            disabled={isSubmitting || Object.keys(errors).length > 0}

            sx={{
              mt: 3,
              mb: 6,
              ...commonStyles.buttonWithBlackColor,
              color: "white",
              bgcolor: "black",
            }}
          >
            {isSubmitting ? <CircularProgress /> : "Submit"}
          </Button>

I want to know why this code cause problem on teh phones not on the PCs and solution.

Difficult to say what might be an issue with this incomplete code example. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] enough a reader could reproduce the problem you describe.
